# Is there a way to lock up a directory with Java?

Tags: windows, locking, directory, directoryentry

My app creates a directory(file folder) on C:/ drive, since I don't want to expose all the data in it, and I don't want to encrypt all files in it, I wonder if there is a way to lock the folder up, so only my app can access it, no other person through windows explorer or another program can open the folder, doesn't matter if my app is running or not, is it doable ?

Comment: Why? Is this storing sensitive user data? Is this storing data that you don't want others to access to prevent pirating? What kind of computer is it running on? Is it running on your servers or is it running on the end user's computer? What kind of information are you trying to secure and why?

Comment: No, but if it is something like a game and you want to keep things challenging you could use a simple rotation cypher or just good ol' rot13 that will put a 1 foot fence around your data.  No mater how advanced you get after that someone will be able to get the data out in probably less time than you invest securing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, operating systems just don't provide this type of facility. You can look at file locks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) but those are intended to prevent "concurrent access" not this sort of "lock". With that said, you should ask yourself what are you trying to do here, is it securing information (encrypted file) or preventing accidental configuration changes (hiding the directory)?

Comment: But hiding the directory doesn't stop changes to it. Hide is not real hide.

Answer (score 2):

This is inherently impossible.
There is nothing that your program can do on the user's machine that he cannot do himself.  (possibly aided by a decompiler and a debugger)